# How to define multiple table select query using sqlite virtual table framework?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have implemented definitions of all sqlite virtual table apis (vtBextIndex,vtColumn,....) and its working perfectly for single table .I want to support read queries with multiple tables(*ex : select t1.col1,t2.col2 from t1,t2*) as well but I am not getting information about list of tables in the read queries .
I tried to find out definition of sqlite3_vtab_cursor for the same but didn't able to find table-name .
**How do I know about all the table-names in the read query when virtual table apis will be invoked ?**

Answer (score 0):

The virtual table API does not give you this information.

Joins are implemented in the SQLite core (always as nested loop joins); you cannot change this.

To optimize joins, you have to implement fast lookup of rows by the joined column(s).